# How to convert core Curl Request to a PHP code request with -X PUT parameters and post data?

Tags: php, curl

I have following curl request from CMD working fine, however i need to convert this into a php request like below function bt for some reason its failing to do so. why ?

```
curl -i 'http://localhost:7557/presets/inform' -X PUT --data '{ "weight": 0, "precondition": "{\"_deviceId._SerialNumber\":\"C8Bsdsd5E372\"}", "configurations": [ { "type": "value", "name": "InternetGatewayDevice.Time.NTPServer1", "value": "ntp1.sddsd.com" }, { "type": "value", "name": "InternetGatewayDevice.Time.NTPServer3", "value": "ntp.dfdfkdshfksfd.org" } ] }'
```

I have written following code as php function but seems to be failing with

Response code 405 (Method not allowed, i believe the problem is the PUT request)

**`405 Method Not Allowed`**

```
$request='{ "weight": 0, "precondition": "{\"_deviceId._SerialNumber\":\"C8Bjkjkjj5E372\"}", "configurations": [ { "type": "value", "name": "InternetGatewayDevice.Time.NTPServer1", "value": "ntp1.sssdssd.com" }, { "type": "value", "name": "InternetGatewayDevice.Time.NTPServer3", "value": "ntp.dfdfkdshfksfd.org" } ] }';

$location='http://localhost:7557/presets/inform';


$response=curlRequest($request,$location);

    function curlRequest($request, $location)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($location);
        $curlOptions = array(
              CURLOPT_URL => $location,
        //    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        //    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        //    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
              CURLOPT_POST => true,
              CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request,
              CURLOPT_PROXY => 'proxy.example.com',
              CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => 8080 ,
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => SOAP_CONN_TIMEOUT,
              CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3,
              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        );
        //
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);
        $response = curl_exec($ch) or die (curl_error($ch));
        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the CUSTOMREQUEST `put`, See below:

```
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT'
```

However, you may also need to send along the Content Type to the server as well:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($$request)));
```

This should make sure the request is `PUT` and the server knows to expect a JSON content type.